# GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed problems in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:5550): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs Since ubuntu updated the GTK version from GTK2 to GTK3.

> g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

The above error can be fixed by changing the ubuntu theme to default using "gnome-tweak-tool" or other utility tools.

But before doing the same, please read upto the end and proceed. Even though the theme related bug donot arise with default theme, there are lot of discrepencies & issues with ubuntu GTK3 and eclipse SWT. For instance you will receive error similar to

> Negative content width -x (allocation y, extents axb) while allocating gadget (node toolbar, owner GtkToolbar)

So it is better to use GTK2 as mentioned in the eclipse forum for the same issue as of now.
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1081230/

To use eclipse with GTK2 either use one of the following steps.

1. Run the command "env SWT_GTK3=0 SWT_WEBKIT2=1 $EclipsePath"
2. Run the command "export SWT_GTK3=0" and then $EclipsePath.

If you are concerned about security, please ensure that $SWT_WEBKIT2 is set to 1 by giving the command "echo $SWT_WEBKIT2"

Each SWT version requires its corresponding GTK dependency.
SWT requires the following GTK+ versions (or newer) to be installed:

```
Eclipse/SWT 4.11.x         : GTK+ 3.10.0 and its dependencies
Eclipse/SWT 4.10.x         : GTK+ 3.8.0 and its dependencies
Eclipse/SWT 4.6.x - 4.9.x  : GTK+ 2.24.0 and its dependencies (for GTK+ 2) OR GTK+ 3.0.0 and its dependencies (for GTK+ 3)
Eclipse/SWT 4.5.x and newer: GTK+ 2.18.0 and its dependencies (for GTK+ 2) OR GTK+ 3.0.0 and its dependencies (for GTK+ 3)
Eclipse/SWT 4.4.x          : GTK+ 2.10.0 and its dependencies (for GTK+ 2) OR GTK+ 3.0.0 and its dependencies (for GTK+ 3)
Eclipse/SWT 4.3.x          : GTK+ 2.10.0 and its dependencies
Eclipse/SWT 3.8.x          : GTK+ 2.6.0 and its dependencies
Eclipse/SWT 3.6.x - 3.7.x  : GTK+ 2.4.1 and its dependencies
Eclipse/SWT 3.0.x - 3.5.x  : GTK+ 2.2.1 and its dependencies
Eclipse/SWT 2.1.x          : GTK+ 2.0.6 and its dependencies
```

This information can be obtained from https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#gtkstartup

To check your SWT version, in eclipse, click

> Help -> About Eclipse IDE -> Installation details -> Configuration tab

search for **org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.version** and choose GTK2 or GTK3 based on your SWT version.

The following flow chart explains the SWT flow hierarchy. To know detailed information about SWT, click https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT/Devel/Gtk/Dev_guide
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with Spring tool suite (which is eclipse based). Try to run eclipse:

```
env SWT_GTK3=0 [STS/Eclipse executable]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had installed GTK and designed aplications by YARU DARK before eclipse installation.

- The solution was to change the look of applications back to default:Yaru